# Getting bash-3.2 everytime I "su"

Tags: bash, sudo

Whenever I su, PS1 changes to \s-\v\$. Why is that? Tried setting it, but it still changes when I su again, or exit the terminal. What to do?

Comment: Try `sudo su -` instead of `sudo su`!

Comment: Or `sudo -s` :-)

Comment: Why would i want to sudo su? It's just switching users